# how to open a file and read contents inside the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh, docker-machine

I have a docker file where i need to open a file and get the data .If the data is dev, i am passing a argument(dev application) and if it is not passing another argument(prod application)to the sh file. It should be something like

```
f=open config.txt
data=f.read()
if data=dev
app=dev application
else
app=prod application

ENTRYPOINT ["./entry.sh app"]
```

here i am trying to pass the argument to the .sh file (entry.sh).so i can use the incoming argument in the entry.sh file. Please help me how to do it in a correct way.
I am new to this Dockerfile.

Comment: can you please explain your exact use case, so then I can help you.

Comment: I am having the env=dev in a config.txt file. I need to take that data(dev/prod) from the file and if it is dev/prod i need to modify the appname accordingly as(dev app/prod app) and pass to the .sh file as a parameter @JijoAlexander

Comment: I updated the answer, please take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments while building the docker image by using the ARG parameters like this. while building you can pass values like `docker build --build-arg ENV_ARG=dev`

**DOCKER FILE CODE SAMPLE**

```
ARG ENV_ARG=prod
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENV_ARG
CMD ["sh", "-c", "entry.sh ${ENVIRONMENT}"]
```